# Must implement abstract method

Tags: java, interface, processing

This is using Processing 3.5, not every java thing works the same here.
The Bird class is giving me the error saying it needs to implement call(). Isn't it already under the main? I'm not experienced with interfaces so I don't know what exactly is going on here.

```
 public interface FuncCall<A> {
   A call();
 }

 class Bird implements FuncCall{
    //Error here ^
    //The type FuncCallTest.Bird must implement the inherited abstract method FuncCallTest.FuncCall.call()
    //Is this not implemented already under main?

   float x, y, size;
   ArrayList<FuncCall<Float>> inputs = new ArrayList<FuncCall<Float>>();

   public Bird(float x, float y, float size){
     this.x = x;
     this.y = y;
     this.size = size;
   }

   public void main(String[] args){

     FuncCall<Float> getX = new FuncCall<Float>(){
       @Override
       public Float call(){
           return x;
         }
     };

     FuncCall<Float> getY = new FuncCall<Float>(){
       @Override
       public Float call(){
         return y;
       }
     };

     FuncCall<Float> getSize = new FuncCall<Float>(){
       @Override
       public Float call(){
         return size;
       }
     };

     inputs.add(getX);
     inputs.add(getY);
     inputs.add(getSize);

   }

 }

 class Pol {

   ArrayList<FuncCall<Float>> inputs = new ArrayList<FuncCall<Float>>();

   public Pol(ArrayList<FuncCall<Float>> inputs){
     this.inputs = inputs;
   }

   //public float call(ArrayList<FuncCall<Float>> arr, int index){
     //return arr.get(index).call();
   //}
   //How do I do this? Do I need to implement the interface here as well? Because if so same error as on Bird

 }
```

I'll also stick this extra bit on the end here.
`System.out.println(pol.call(pol.inputs, 1));`
Does will that work? It doesn't error before compiling.
I appreciate any help. Please ask if something doesn't make sense as I'm still new to stack and not the best with java. :)
main file :

```
 void setup(){

   Bird bird = new Bird(1.2, 3.2, 7.5);
   Pol pol = new Pol(bird.inputs);
   System.out.println(pol.call(pol.inputs, 1););
 }
```

Comment: Your *class* needs to implement the `call` method if you really want to implement `FuncCall`. But maybe `Bird` simply shouldn't implement `FuncCall`. If someone were to write `Bird bird = new Bird(); bird.call();` what would you expect to happen?

Comment: @JonSkeet I needed the interface so my other class could access the array of functions and call them. i just put in a call() that returns 0 and now it can't run the sketch at all. VM failed to initialize. I don't intend on bird needing to call it tho, just pol

Comment: "I needed the interface so my other class could access the array of functions and call them." No you don't. Unless you call `call()` *on the Bird instance itself* then you don't need `Bird` to implement the interface.

Comment: Not sure I fully understand. you're right that the class didn't need it but how am I going to access the functions from another class? Also it still won't run the sketch :(

Comment: Well you haven't shown anything creating an instance of Bird or what you'd do with it, so it's hard to say, I'm afraid

Comment: @JonSkeet does that help? I'm still trying to figure all this out. I know that it doesn't fit with the edits you've suggested.

Comment: Right, so you're using `bird.inputs` already. No need for `Bird` to implement `FuncCall` at all. (It's not obvious what the purpose of `Pol` is at all, but that's a different matter...)

Comment: @JonSkeet I won't get into all the plans. Can you tell me from here how I could make a method in pol to call one of those methods from `bird.inputs`? (say, get bird.y but have it in a method of pol) Is this possible or am I going down a dead end?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. You're getting the functions from `bird.inputs` - you could iterate over those, or fetch a single element, the same way you normally do from an `ArrayList`.

Comment: Saying `pol.inputs.get(i);` doesn't return the functions output though. How can I do that and get the function to run?

Comment: Quick follow up I believe I have it. First I solved the problem with it not running but that's unrelated. I've done is `pol.inputs.get(i).call()` and it seems to work perfect! Do you see anything wrong?

Comment: Yes, but you should still check whether you need `pol` at all, given that it just copies the functions from `bird`.

Comment: @JonSkeet is right.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yeah it's all working great now. I need `Pol` because of the  future plans for this project, obviously right now it's useless. Thanks for all the help though!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you could skip your FuncCall interface and use Java's Supplier functional interface and just add these Suppliers respectively method references of your class objects getters to the list.
Another approach is to provide an interface or abstract class that has getters and/or member variables for x, y and size and use this interface or abstract class as type parameter for the list.

1. With Suppliers:
   This is closer to your example and requires less changes in
   your code.
   The second option with an interface changes your Pol class
   completely and I am not sure if this is acceptable for you.

´

```
public class Bird {

      private float x;
      private float y;
      private float size;

       public Bird(float x, float y, float size) {
           //set your members here
       }

       public Float getX() {
            return this.x;
        }

        public Float getY() {
            return this.y;
        }

         public Float getSize() {
             return this.size;
          }
}
```

´
Then the Pol class
´

```
public class Pol {

    private final List<Supplier<Float>> inputs;

    public Pol(List<Supplier<Float>> inputs) {
         this.inputs = inputs;
     }

     public Float call(int index) {
         return this.inputs.get(index).get();
     }
}
```

´
And your main should look like
´

```
public static int main(String[] args) {

    Bird bird = new Bird(1.0f, 1.0f, 2.5f);

     Pol pol = new Pol(Arrays.asList(bird::getX, 
     bird::getY, bird::getSize));
     Float birdsSize = pol.call(2);

     return 0;
}
```

´

Comment: Is the first par talking about lambdas? becuase they do not work in processing. Could I get more details about the second half perhaps?